# Issue with a first-class linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a newbie at programming at C and I am learning from a book so I apologize if the following is too basic.  I am trying to implement first-class linked lists and the following program when executed gives me the error "Segmentation fault: 11".

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node* link;
typedef struct node {int item; link next;} node;
typedef struct linked_list {link head; link tail;} linked_list; 

int main(void)
{
    link x;
    x = malloc(sizeof(node));
    x->next = NULL;
    x->item = 12;

    linked_list* l;
    l->head = x;
}
```

The same program without the linked list pointer and instead just with:

```
linked_list l;
l.head = x;
```

runs just fine.  However, I'll need multiple lists around so I will ultimately want the pointer and I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.  Does anyone know a possible solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `l` is not allocated, so you can't access it's `head`.

Comment: initilize the pointer, now it has no memory.

Comment: Don't hide pointers with typedefs. This very bad practice and it only causes confusion, When I see `link next`, I have no freaking idea what `next` is. But when I see `struct node *link`, then I know exactly what `link` is.

Comment: @l_frost What is the "first-class linked-list implementation"?! These words "first class", as for example "first class objects" do not make a sense and are used by low-qualified authors of books on programming that only confuse readers of such books. Do not use this senseless term.

Comment: For the link x pointer (ie node* x) you have reserved memory! So the linked_list* l pointer you need to do the same.

Comment: As a beginner, you should avoid not only hiding pointer nature behind typedefs, but using typedefs at all.  There is nothing you can do with them that you cannot do without, and they tend to be a source of confusion, especially for beginners.  The whole thing is a concept that would be best left for later (though I am aware that C textbooks frequently do not follow this recommendation).  I rarely use them in my own programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to implement first-class linked lists

The term "first class linked list" is senseless. Actually what you are trying to implement is a two-sided singly-linked list.

In this code snippet

```
linked_list* l;
l->head = x;
```

you are using an uninitialized pointer `l` that has an indeterminate value. So dereferencing it results in undefined behavior.

Instead you could write for example

```
linked_list l = { .head = x, .tail = x };
```

declaring an object of the structure type and initializing its both data members.

If you want to use pointers to linked lists then allocate objects of the type `linked_list` dynamically as for example

```
linked_list* l = malloc( sizeof( *l ) );
l->head = x;
l->tail = x;
```

Strictly speaking initially the lists should be empty.

```
linked_list* l = malloc( sizeof( *l ) );
l->head = NULL;
l->tail = NULL;
```

You need to write a function that will add new nodes to the linked lists.

Comment: I agree that "first-class linked list" is not a standard term, but I suspect that what the OP means is having a data structure to represent the list itself, *containing* the head pointer, as opposed to using a bare head pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That only confuses others because this term is irresponsibly used in many other contexts.

Comment: Yes, without context, the term _"first-class"_ is suggestive of things like _the very best_, or _superior_.  It does not naturally bring to mind what might actually be a category or chapter name used to distinguish a type of `struct`  in a poorly written book on C.

Comment: Thank you Vlad and everyone else -- this was very discussion for me.